# Refactor code duplication of XCTestAssertions in a seperate method while writing unit test cases in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, refactoring, xctest

I have a unit test class with multiple test cases. Some test cases have common XCTest Assertions. These test cases implements an API call. This API call can have different input request parameters but the response is same. I have put test assertions on response. So, is it good by design to extract out this common assertions code on response in a separate method (not a test method) and call that method in the test methods?

Below is the code for reference:

```
- (void)testRequest {
AppType app = @"A";
NSDictionary *requestMessage = @{requestMessage};
__block BOOL hasReceivedResponse = NO;
[Class handleRequestMessage:requestMessage
                  appType:app
     managedObjectContext:self.fixtures.managedObjectContext
          completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *responseMessage, NSError *error) {
                                     XCTAssertNil(error);
                                     NSString *name = responseMessage[@"name"];
                                     XCTAssert([name isEqualToString:@"Search"]);

                                     NSString *response = responseMessage[@"response"];
                                     XCTAssert([response isEqualToString:@"1"]);

                                     hasReceivedResponse = YES;
                          }];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilCompletionIndicator:&hasReceivedResponse];
}
```

Here appType can be A, B, C. Response as present in completion block remains the same. Can I extract completion block code to a separate method?

Refactored Code:

```
- (BOOL)receivedResponseForRequestMessage:(NSDictionary *)responseMessage error:(NSError *)error {
XCTAssertNil(error);
                                     NSString *name = responseMessage[@"name"];
                                     XCTAssert([name isEqualToString:@"Search"]);

                                     NSString *response = responseMessage[@"response"];
                                     XCTAssert([response isEqualToString:@"1"]);
}

-(void)testRequestForA {
AppType app = @"A";
NSDictionary *requestMessage = @{requestMessage};
__block BOOL hasReceivedResponse = NO;
[Class handleRequestMessage:requestMessage
                  appType:app
     managedObjectContext:self.fixtures.managedObjectContext
          completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *responseMessage, NSError *error) {
hasReceivedResponse = [self receivedResponseForRequestMessage:responseMessage error:error
                          }];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilCompletionIndicator:&hasReceivedResponse];
}

-(void)testRequestForB {
AppType app = @"B";
NSDictionary *requestMessage = @{requestMessage};
__block BOOL hasReceivedResponse = NO;
[Class handleRequestMessage:requestMessage
                  appType:app
     managedObjectContext:self.fixtures.managedObjectContext
          completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *responseMessage, NSError *error) {
hasReceivedResponse = [self receivedResponseForRequestMessage:responseMessage error:error
                          }];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilCompletionIndicator:&hasReceivedResponse];
}
```

Is this kind of refactoring correct by design?

Comment: I assume `-[NSRunLoop runUntilCompletionIndicator:]` is a custom extension, predating XCTestExpectation

Answer (score 0):

Having a common XCTAssert does have at least one drawback. XCTAssert reports its line number, which enables you to find the failing test and quickly fix it. When your method `testRequestForA` fails, the failing line will be in `receivedResponseForRequestMessage:error:`.

One thing you can do in Objective-C is pass in a message after the expression being asserted. According to the docs, this is "An optional description of the failure. A literal NSString, optionally with string format specifiers." Your test results will contain this information, so if you identified the assertion well it will be easy to find the source line.

`XCTAssert([response isEqualToString:@"1"], @"%@ response failed", name); // Replace name with another string if appropriate`

As a side note, Swift also allows you to also pass in the line number and/or file where the test failed, which makes it a lot easier to use assertions in helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's helpful to refactor test code to make it more expressive. This includes extracting assertion helpers.

In practice, this isn't easy to do in the Objective-C because assertions like `XCTAssert` are actually macros. They need to be macros at the call site in order to pick up `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. Unfortunately Apple chose to implement them entirely as macros, instead of as thin macros which call methods taking file name and line number arguments.

But in [How to Structure Tests that Do Real Networking](https://qualitycoding.org/asynchronous-tests/), I recommend *not* putting assertions within a block. Instead, have the block capture its arguments, and trigger the exit. This avoids issues with timeouts, and moves assertions to the end of the test where they are easier to read.

This would change the first part of your example to this:

```
- (void)testRequest {
    AppType app = @"A";
    NSDictionary *requestMessage = @{requestMessage};
    __block BOOL hasReceivedResponse = NO;
    __block NSDictionary *capturedResponseMessage = nil;
    __block NSError *capturedError = nil;
    [Class handleRequestMessage:requestMessage
                      appType:app
         managedObjectContext:self.fixtures.managedObjectContext
              completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *responseMessage, NSError *error) {
                                        capturedResponseMessage = responseMessage;
                                        capturedError = error;
                                        hasReceivedResponse = YES;
                              }];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilCompletionIndicator:&hasReceivedResponse];
```

The `hasReceivedResponse` trigger can be replaced by an XCTestExpectation. This would let you use a timeout.

Now we can perform assertions against the captured arguments. But I'm going to change the assertions:

```
    XCTAssertNil(error, @"error");
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(responseMessage[@"name"], @"Search", @"name");
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(responseMessage[@"response"], @"1", @"response");
}
```

First, I replaced the `XCTAssert` … `isEqualToString:` with `XCTAssertEqualObjects`. This is important, because when the assertion fails, it will report the 2 values that weren't equal instead of just "Failed". You can immediately see what the actual value was without using the debugger.

I also added a message to each assertion. This can be important when you have multiple assertions in a single test. It may not matter when sitting in front of your IDE, because you can click on a failure message to see which assertion triggered it. But when tests are running on a CI server, we want to log more information so that any failures can be diagnosed without hunting down line numbers.

If you still want to extract common assertions, I'd recommend either:

- Write them entirely as macros so you get `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. Look at the definition of `XCTAssert` to get started.
- Use [OCHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest) and write a custom matcher. Because OCHamcrest takes care of capturing file name and line number, the matcher is easier to write.

However, pulling the assertions out of the block made them so short they're hardly worth extracting. I'd focus instead on extracting a helper for the first part, capturing the block arguments.